# Can a shared method be multithreaded?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

As the question states, can a shared method of an object be multithreaded?  I don't quite having threading down in my skillset, otherwise I would test myself.  On the other hand, I am involved in designing class that could be part of a multithreaded application in VB.Net.

Comment: If you are designing classes that could be part of a multithreaded application, it might be time to get threading into your skillset?

Comment: Yes, I will agree.  I love opportunities where you are required to learn something you interested in.  This happens to be one of those opportunities :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean "is it safe for a shared method to be called from multiple threads at once" - the answer is "it depends". A method itself isn't multi-threaded or single-threaded; threads and methods are very separate things.

If your shared method is called from multiple threads, then unless there's any synchronization to say otherwise, it will be executed concurrently on those threads. That can definitely cause a problem *if* your method uses shared state without appropriate safeguards. However, if the method either takes care when accessing shared resources (e.g. using locks) *or* it doesn't access any state which is shared between threads, that's fine.

Comment: Good to know the the shared states. In Jon Skeet we trust. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can. Any method can become a thread.

Comment: @hydroparadise: Yup. They'll be executed separately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, shared methods can be executed simultaneously by multiple threads. **In fact, they often are.** You do not have as much control over which threads are executing shared methods as compared to instance methods. Consider an ASP.NET application for example. Different page requests may come in on different threads. If you call a shared method in your web application then there is a high probability that it is getting executed by multiple threads.

This is an incredibly important point when designing an API. All self respecting API authors go to extremes to make sure all shared/static methods are thread-safe. Afterall, it would be ridiculously onerous to make a caller of your API synchronize access to every single shared/static method you provide. Take a look at the documentation Microsoft provides for almost all classes in the BCL.

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

I have yet to run across a static method provided by Microsoft that was not thread-safe.<sup>1</sup> And that is good because it makes life easier for you and I.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you know of one let me know.